# Guo Hall iterattions don't persist

Tags: c, do-while

I am implementing the guo hall algorithm for a micro controller. The problem is due to it's architecture  I cannot use opencv. I have the algorithm working fine except for one problem. in the following code a struct is passed through the thinning iterator the struct contains both the 2d array and a boolean determining whether or not change was made to the array.

```
int* thinning(int* it, int x, int y)
{
    for(int i= 0; i < x*y; ++i)
        it[i] /= 255;

    struct IterRet base;
    base.i = it;
    base.b = false;

    do 
    {
        base = thinningIteration(base, x, y, 0);
        base = thinningIteration(base, x, y, 1);
    }
    while (base.b);

    for(int i= 0; i < x*y; ++i)
        base.i[i] *= 255;


    return base.i;
}
```

when I change the while condition to `while(0)` A single iteration passes and the matrix is properly returned.

When I leave the while loop as is, it goes on indefinitely.
I have narrowed the problem down to the fact that base is reset after each run of the do-while loop. 
What would cause this? I can give more code if this is too narrow of a view for it.

Comment: ***[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)***.  Need enough definition to compile, run and debug, i.e. `struct IterRet`, function def. `thinningIteration(...)`, etc.

Comment: You can get the full code at:
http://pastebin.com/WMAeMrcm
a copy of feep.pgm is also available 
http://pastebin.com/BL7QEQmX

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code as it is, it did not go on indefinitely, but ran through once, and stopped.  However, there are two places where I made a suggested change.  Really just a readability/style thing, not something that will change the behavior of your code in this case.

See commented and replacement lines below.

***In thinningIteration()***

```
struct IterRet thinningIteration(struct IterRet it, int x, int y, int iter)
{
    //int* marker = malloc(x*y* sizeof *marker);
    int* marker = malloc(x*y* sizeof(int));
```

***In main()***

```
//int* src = malloc( sizeof *src * x * y);
int* src = malloc( sizeof (int) * x * y);
```

Unfortunately, these edits did *not* address the main issue you asked about, but again, running the code did not exhibit the behavior you described.

If you can add more about the nature of your observed issues, please leave a comment, and if I can, will attempt to help.

Comment: I forgot to uncomment line 46. That is what causes the infinite loop.